Astro Theme: Modify submenu (entries too far apart)
I am using the Astro theme which offers a lot of options. Nevertheless, it has no solution for my problem. In my opinion, the entries in the submenu are too far apart. This I would like to reduce line height. How would I do this with additional CSS? Thank you.

